# Unable to pass access token as a variable in Node Js Websocket while doing New KiteTicker - Zerodha Kite Websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am trying to create a ticker to get tick data on daily market open and I am trying to pass access_token from a variable where the ticker is not working. Can someone advise if I am doing it the right way.

```
var KiteTicker = require("kiteconnect").KiteTicker;
var ticker = new KiteTicker({
api_key: apikey,
access_token: accesstokenprint,
});
```

I tried to create the variable as global and try to pass it as mentioned on the code